# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive/send

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, office-365-developer

I'm using the below script to copy the files from source library to destination library. Script run successfully but after certain period i am getting the below error.

I've close to 20000 items in source library to copy. Can one help on how to resolve this issue?

Error: Copy-PnPFile : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive/send.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
$SiteURL = "your site collection URL"
$SourceFolderURL = "/sites/site collection name/document library name"
$TargetFolderURL = "/sites/site collection name/document library name"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
#Copy All Files and Folders between source and target folders
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $SourceFolderURL -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -SkipSourceFolderName -Force -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting to the document: [Copy-PnPFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/copy-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)

> Currently there is a 200MB file size limit for the file or folder to
> be copied.

I have tested with the `Copy-PnPFile` command and it works fine. I suppose you do not have the same issue if you run the script in a smaller library.

Try moving the documents in the source document library into multiple folders and then run the script on one of the folders again. See if you will reproduce this issue.